# use Table valued function return value in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a table-valued function which return 2 columns and 1 row. I would like to use those values in the select statement. Kindly help me in fetching the value from table.

**Edit** (From OP's comments)

something like

```
select a,b (select c1 from MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2)) as c, 
           (select c2 from MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2)) as d 
from main_table
```

Comment: Post what you have got already. Also, what platform are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its Sql Server, this is as simple as:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 
FROM Schema.MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2);
```

**Edit**

If the parameters passed to the Function are constants / independent of the other joined tables, you can use a `CROSS JOIN` to it, alias it and use the result columns.

```
SELECT a,b, X.Col1 as c, X.Col2 as d 
FROM main_table mt
 CROSS JOIN MyTableFunction(123, 'SomeConstant') AS X;
```

However, if you need to pass in columns from a table into a table valued function during a join, you need to use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT a,b, X.Col1 as c, X.Col2 as d 
FROM main_table mt
 CROSS APPLY MyTableFunction(mt.Col1, mt.Col2) AS X;
```

Comment: i need to use in another select Query, something like select a,b (select c1 from MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2)) as c, (select c2 from MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2)) as d from main_table

Comment: i need to use it in another select Query, something like select a,b (select c1 from MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2)) as c, (select c2 from MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2)) as d from main_table

Comment: @Rajakrishnan: Still we don't know your database platform.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server just put the function name in the from. So:

```
select column1
,      column2
from   dbo.udFunctionName('xyz')
```

In Oracle use:

```
select column1
,      column2
from   table(functionName('xyz'))
```

Comment: I SQL Query . i need to use it in another select Query, something like select a,b (select c1 from MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2)) as c, (select c2 from MyTableFunction(Param1, Param2)) as d from main_table